# Different validation loss in model.fit and model.evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, recommendation-engine

Following  [two tower model tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/main/docs/examples/deep_recommenders.ipynb) ,   I made  my recommendation model. Then I trained it for one epoch  and evaluated it:

```
cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(4096)
cached_test = test.batch(4096).cache()

model = Model( layer_sizes = [    32 ], use_context=False)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.001))
history = model.fit(cached_train, validation_data = cached_test, validation_freq=1,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback],
                    epochs=1)
```

this model has  following log (val_total_loss is  less than training loss) :

```
684/684 [==============================] - 195s 284ms/step 
-  factorized_top_k/top_100_categorical_accuracy: 0.1404 - loss: 33958.1878 - regularization_loss: 0.0000e+00 - total_loss: 33958.1878 - val_factorized_top_k/top_100_categorical_accuracy: 0.1185 - val_loss: 25582.6953 - val_regularization_loss: 0.0000e+00 - **val_total_loss: 25582.6953**
```

Then I evaluated accuracy by model.evaluate  :

```
test_accuracy = model.evaluate(
    cached_test, return_dict=True)
```

```
171/171 [==============================] - 34s 197ms/step - 

- factorized_top_k/top_100_categorical_accuracy: 0.1185 - loss: 33966.4893 - regularization_loss: 0.0000e+00 - **total_loss: 33966.4893**
```

Even though  I didn't  change  model after training one epoch, total_loss in `model.evaluate(cached_test)` is different from the value I got by `model.fit`.

Why is this  happening ?

Comment: Have you checked your dataloaders and randomness values?

Comment: Yes, even though  I shuffled  data several times I got same result

Comment: Yes, that's why you should not shuffle it.

Comment: It is obvious that when we set shuffle =True, we may expect slight change in the final solutions. One more reason is neural networks use `Float32` format which is not so accurate as `Float64`. Set shuffle=False and train the model. You will see not much change in loss.  Thanks!